# What does Sheldon Cooper mean by this statement?

Tags: dialogue, the-big-bang-theory

In *The Big Bang Theory* S4E12, Sheldon made the following comment on Penny's idea of the 'Shoe App':

> The simple-mindedness of your idea is exceeded only by its crass consumerism and banality.

Can anyone explain what is he trying to say in layman's terms?

Comment: He's saying her idea is stupid, and useless...
*I have to ask, Is there any specific reason why you put Sheldon's credentials in title?*

Comment: This appears to be a simple English language comprehension question & may have been a better fit for [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple-minded = Stupid
Crass = stupid and insensitive
Consumerism = Obsession with material objects and wealth
Banality = Boring and unoriginal

So, in layman's terms: "Your idea is stupid, greedy, and boring."